# How i can get the total size for all our site collections including OneDrive sites

Tags: administration, pnp-powershell, pnp

I want to get the total size for all our SharePoint sites (including OneDrive sites), where i tried to run this PnP command:-

```
Get-PnPTenantSite -IncludeOneDriveSites -Detailed
```

but i could not get the size of the sites.. can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$sites =Get-PnPTenantSite -IncludeOneDriveSites

foreach($s in $sites)
{
  write-host "Usage:$($s.StorageUsage) MB `t MaxLevel:$($s.StorageMaximumLevel) MB `t Url:$($s.Url)"

}
```

MS Doc [reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnptenantsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

**Updating to confirm PnP PowerShell returns values in MBs**

To manually check the allocated quota follow steps 1 and 2.

1. Click on Settings gear and then select Site Settings
2. In the "Site Settings" page, under "Site Collection Administration", click on **Storage Metrics**

[image]

3. To convert 25600 GB to MB, multiply with 1024 (1 GB = 1024 MB), which gives **26214400 MB**
4. Compare this with the PnP PS output value of **StorageMaximumLevel**, which in my case is **MaxLevel:26214400 MB**

**Conclusion**: PnP PowerShell returns Storage Metrics in MBs

Comment: thanks a lot, but can i get the total size of all those sites as one number?

Comment: will this satisfy my need `$sites =Get-PnPTenantSite -IncludeOneDriveSites
$t=0;
foreach($s in $sites)
{
  write-host "Usage:$($s.StorageUsage) MB `t MaxLevel:$($s.StorageMaximumLevel) MB `t Url:$($s.Url)"
$t=$t+$s.StorageUsage

} 
write-host $t `

Comment: I think so. You can manually check the returned value for couple of them by going into the site collection then Storage metrics to make sure the number is accurate. If the individual numbers are accurate, sum should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but from where i can confirm that the `StorageUsage` will be in MB and not in GB?

Comment: can you advice on my above comment? just to make sure that the size will be in MB before i accept your answer...thanks

Comment: Please see the updates in my original response. Hope this clears the confusion. Let me know if you still have any questions

Comment: ok thanks.......